# CSS - Class is moving out of position

Tags: html, css

i should make something like:

[image]

But it actualy looks like:

[image]

As u can see on images "left" class is moving out of its possition with no reason when i add image or text there, and i am 100% sure that text or image is smaller then width / height of block so i really dont know how to continue and fix this.

My HTML:

```
 <div id="sub-content">
    <span class="left">
    <img src="images/foto.png">
    <span class="topic-name"> Název topicu nebo článku </span>
    </span>
    <span class="middle"></span>
    <span class="right"></span>
 </div>
```

My CSS:

```
#sub-content{
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-image: url("images/sub_content_bg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 145px;
    width: 987px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#sub-content .left{
    width: 326px;
    height: 145px;
    display: inline-block;        
}

#sub-content .left img{
    width: 122px;
    height: 121px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-left: 5px;        
}

#sub-content .left .topic-name{
    width: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 130px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 14px;         
} 

#sub-content .middle{
    background-color: orange;
    width: 326px;
    height: 145px;
    display: inline-block;         
}

#sub-content .right{
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 326px;
    height: 145px;
    display: inline-block;         
}
```

Please can somebody help me to style this or tell me what i am doing wrong?

p.s. Live preview can be also find on: funedit.com/andurit/new/

Comment: feels like a `vertical-align:top` issue when using `inline-block`

Comment: Also, spans should not really contain divs. if you need a block, use a block level element.

Comment: Why are you using a div inside a span?

Comment: I just edit <div> to <span> on my localhost, also can remove vertical-align:top; but first one dont change anything and second one just change position of text not whole block;

Comment: I change that span to div even in here, i am sorry for that guys but i am new in CSS, anyway it didnt help to fix my problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `overflow:hidden` to the `.left` `div`, it will align correctly.

See: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/dxcjf/)

(I also replaced the inner `span` with `div` since `div` shouldn't occur inside `span`).

Comment: right , overflow hidden just dont put anything on place where it shouldnt be, but i feel like its not most correct way to fix it now. Because for example i cant move things upper then its the block and because block is moved down a bit i am in trubble

Comment: You should use it in the other blocks as well. See: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/dxcjf/2/

Comment: Yes. There are other ways to do it. You can use `float:left` in those blocks and then control the `margin-left` of each block. You can also use relative or absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a `position` propery to your CSS file. In `#sub-content`, add `position:static;`. This should make the elements render in order as they appear in the document.

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your answer but isnt position:static default value?

Comment: It might be, I don't quite remember.. Some times I have notised that if I use `float:left;` on all the elements that I want to align, they tend to "fix" them selves. It's worth a try..